# Handle GCM notification Android

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am developing an app wich receives GCM notifications to alert the user about promotions and stuff like that.

So far i have managed to send and receive notifications. Here is my code:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

}

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {
public static final int notifyID = 1337;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
       sendNotification(extras.getString("type"),extras.getString("msg"));
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String type, String msg) {
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("type", type);
    resultIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)      
            .setContentTitle("x")
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    int defaults = 0;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
    mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
}
```

}

The problem is that i don't know how (or where) to show a message alert.

Searching on the web, i found an implementation where the message was shown even when the app was closed, but i only need to show the message on the app, for example: when the app is open or when the app is closed and the user opens it.

Answer (score 0):

The Android notification framework is designed to show notifications irrespective of whether or not your app is open. Notifications are shown in the notification bar on the top and do not show within your activity screen.

If you do not want to show notifications when the app is not running, you can do something like have a variable isRunning and set it to true in onResume() of an activity and false in onPause() of an activity. This way, you now have a reference to find out if the app is running or not. If isRunning is false, then you can save the notifications that you are receiving in the background into a SharedPreferences or database - you will do this without using the Notification framework. If the app is open, then you can show a message alert - either using the Notification framework if that is what you intend to do or use an AlertDialog.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information. How can i implement the variable "isRunning" in all my Activities in an easy way?

Comment: you could use SharedPreferences to persist the variable across different sessions. or you could store the value in a database and retrieve it everytime but SharedPreferences will be easier